# Paper error HP Officejet Pro 8620

Tags: printer

We want to print on company paper (it's got a big dark green block on the   right corner) and that blocks the paper sensor. Other paper goes fine.

Comment: LOL :) I suggest you take it up with HP. Alternatively put the paper upside down and print on the "back"

Answer (score 0):

Stick a light-colored Post-it over the block.  As long as the glue edge feeds first, it shouldn't have a feeding problem.